# Finding Cointegration

Tags: variance

https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1404905.

Hello everyone,

In the link above, Meucci explains that in order to find a combination leading to cointegration of several series X , you have to find the vector w which minimise the quantity Var(w'X). I do not understand why we want to minimise variance. Because stationarity needs constant variance and not the smallest possible variance.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Wrong forum for this question.

Comment: I do not understand why ? This question implies quadratic function, PCA, and stationarity is'nt it ?